# During the table echo how would I replace all digits using regex?

Tags: php, html

During the table echo how would I replace all digits using regex?

I wish to use regex to replace all digits with a span holding the digits so I can change their class.

I can't add the spans during the echo because the table is pulled from a text file and echo'd on screen, it would have to replace the digits already pulled in from the text file.

PHP:

```
//set file
$filename='schedule.txt';
//open
$handler=fopen('schedule.txt','r');
//read through file
$file=fread($handler,filesize($filename));
$lines=explode("\r\n",$file);
etc....
```

Comment: Do you understand the difference between server-side and client-side code?

Comment: Why don't you just put the `span`s there in the first place when you echo it in PHP?

Comment: It would make more sense to do the replace in PHP before it even gets to the browser.

Comment: How would I handle it in PHP?

Comment: I wish to replace all digits in the text file with a span that encloses the digit, which is in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
$changed_lines = preg_replace('#(\d+)#', '<span class="bla">$1</span>', $lines);
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thank you for the constructive answer.

Comment: My only question is what does that $1 do? I know $& in JS gives back your search item.

Comment: @Event_Horizon I am capturing the value using brackets `()`, `$1` is the first captured value (and the only one in this example).

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the lines using `foreach()` and then replace using `preg_replace()`:

```
foreach ($lines as $line){

    $line = preg_replace('!\d+!', '<span>$0</span>', $line);
    echo "$line\r\n";
}
```

Using this input:

```
woo yay 19 foo
foo 12 bar
```

I get this output:

```
woo yay <span>19</span> foo
foo <span>12</span> bar
```

If that's not what you're looking for, please updated your question with a concrete example.